# PayPal Personal Payments in Live mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

our website works very well in Sandbox. We are using Adaptive Payments to implement Personal Payments (directly from one person to other), and now we want to test our functions in Live mode.

But when we read the Application Policies to go Live (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-application-policies-and-guidelines) we surprised to find next:

> PayPal - Application Policies
>
> - The Merchant/Seller of Record must be the primary recipient for every PayPal transaction made between a payment Sender (Buyer) and the associated payment Recipient (Seller).

(we use like a sender a person and like primary recipient, a friend of that person)

> - Do not use PayPal API operation calls to provide Personal Payments in India, Mexico, Malaysia, Singapore, and Taiwan.

(we are in Spain)

> - Do not expand Personal payments or provide remittance services for any transactions provided via PayPal services.

So, is there any problem to use Adaptive Payments (Personal Payments) in Live mode ?

Thanks in advance.